# For Some Timezones, Corrected Time after setting TimeZone via JodaTime and java.time are giving different results, Why?

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, jodatime, java-time

Following is a small code snippet in java trying to convert a time in millis to a readable date time format,

```
Long timeInMillis=1615806808301l; //2021-03-15T16:43:28.301+05:30 IST

String timeZone="Europe/Istanbul";

MutableDateTime  mdateTime  = new MutableDateTime(timeInMills);
mdateTime.setZone(DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone)));

ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(timeInMills), ZoneId.of(timeZone));
```

Following are the results given by the Joda[mdateTime] and Java.time[zdt] for the same timeInmillis and timezone,

```
Europe/Istanbul
2021-03-15T13:13:28.301+02:00[Europe/Istanbul]
2021-03-15T14:13:28.301+03:00[Europe/Istanbul]

Turkey
2021-03-15T13:13:28.301+02:00
2021-03-15T14:13:28.301+03:00[Turkey]

Europe/Moscow
2021-03-15T15:13:28.301+04:00
2021-03-15T14:13:28.301+03:00[Europe/Moscow]

Europe/Minsk
2021-03-15T14:13:28.301+03:00
2021-03-15T14:13:28.301+03:00[Europe/Minsk]
```

As you can see, For Some Timezones, the results are different,

**PS: My actual Intention is not to convert the timeInmillis to a readable date time format, but to understand why the results are different.**

PS: The System Timezone was IST[+05:30]

Comment: Check the following notice at the [Home Page of Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/): 
*Joda-Time is the de facto standard date and time library for Java prior to Java SE 8. Users are now asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310).*

Comment: As an aside, with Joda-Time I recommend the simpler `new DateTime(timeInMillis, DateTimeZone.forID(timeZone))`. Under no circumstances involve the old `TimeZone` class. It is poorly designed, and both Joda-Time and java.time offer fully valid replacements.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results with Joda-Time 2.9.9. For all of Europe/Istanbul, Turkey and Europe/Moscow I get `2021-03-15T14:13:28.301+03:00`.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses, 
The issue was with my Joda version, I was using an older version of Joda(2.1), upgrading it to the latest version fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the results you are showing for Joda-Time, you likely are using a very old version.

Time zones change at the whim of governments.  It's very important to always use the latest version and to stay on top of updates.

Upgrade to the current version of Joda-Time (2.10.10 at the time of writing this) and the discrepancy you reported should go away.

Comment: Thanks, Indeed this was a version issue, I was using Joda 2.1, Upgrading to the latest version fixed this issue,

Comment: @FredricFrancis Each version of *Joda-Time*, Java, operating systems, and some databases (such as Postgres), come with their own copy of the [*tzdata* time zone data file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) file. You must keep all of these up-to-date when any time zone you care about is changing its rules.